# Консоль не компилируется class файл из java

Tags: java, cmd, консоль

Не создается файл .class 
Ошибки в коде точно нет, тестил даже на самом простейшем примере HelloWorld. на команду ***javac HelloWorld.java*** никак не отвечает **(Ошибок консоль не выдает,просто нет никакого фидбэка от консоли)**. Windows 10 Pro
Прописаны:

> **CLASSPATH** C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin
>   **JAVA** C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\javaw.exe
>   **JAVA_HOME** C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111
>   **JRE_HOME** C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111
>   **Path** C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin;
>
> > *-version
> >
> >     Java version "1.8.0_111"
> >
> >     Java(TM) SE Runtime Enviroment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
> >
> >     Java HotSpot(TM) 65-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)*

Comment: Все то это конечно понятно, но а где код то? Какую ошибку пишет при попытке компиляции?

Comment: CLASSPATH указывает на странное место

Comment: В том то и дело, что ничего не происходит, нет ошибок

Comment: @Daniel В IDE компилируется?

Comment: @Владимир, да, в эклипсе все работает.

Comment: @Daniel Вот [здесь](http://www.cyberforum.ru/java/thread137970.html) внимательно прочитай и сделай, а затем напиши, что не получилось.

Comment: @Владимир E:\JavaTest\src>javac calc/Base.java
calc\Base.java:7: error: <identifier> expected
    public statiё void main (String args[]) {
                 ^
calc\Base.java:7: error: invalid method declaration; return type required<br>
    public statiё void main (String args[]) {
                       ^
2 errors

Comment: @Daniel Что-то сдается мне, что где-то в коде ошибка. Добавь код программы в вопрос. Метод `main` правильно написан?

Comment: @Владимир ctrl+c ctrl+v из статьи, которую Вы скинули в комментарии.